# Is there a simpler way to convert a byte array to a 2-byte-size hexadecimal string?

Tags: java, arrays, hex

Is there a simpler way of implement this? Or a implemented method in JDK or other lib?

```
/**
 * Convert a byte array to 2-byte-size hexadecimal String.
 */
public static String to2DigitsHex(byte[] bytes) {
String hexData = "";
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    int intV = bytes[i] & 0xFF; // positive int
    String hexV = Integer.toHexString(intV);
    if (hexV.length() < 2) {
    hexV = "0" + hexV;
    }
    hexData += hexV;
}
return hexData;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println(to2DigitsHex(new byte[] {8, 10, 12}));
}
```

the output is: "08 0A 0C" (without the spaces)

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `08 0A 0C`?

Comment: @Toon: Without the 3 at the end (typo?), yeah.

Comment: Clearly, I should've spent more time answering the question and less time making obvious comments (with typos, no less). Or I can just claim BalusC is just too fast for a mere human. Yeah.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Apache Commons-Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) has the [Hex](http://commons.apache.org/codec/api-release/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html) class, which will do what you need:

```
String hexString = Hex.encodeHexString(bytes);
```

By far the easiest method. Don't mess with binary operators, use the libraries to do the dirty work =)

Answer (score 7):

Use at least [`StringBuilder#append()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead of `stringA += stringB` to improve performance and  save memory.

```
public static String binaryToHexString(byte[] bytes) {
    StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(bytes.length * 2);
    for (byte b : bytes) {
        int i = (b & 0xFF);
        if (i < 0x10) hex.append('0');
        hex.append(Integer.toHexString(i));
    }
    return hex.toString();
}
```

Comment: With all due respect, one still MUST cast byte variable _b_ to int, otherwise _b < 0x10_ will be triggered for the negative byte values and the result will be corrupted. 
_int n = b & 0xFF; if (n < 0x10)_ would solve that problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String to2DigitsHex(final byte[] bytes) {
    final StringBuilder accum = new StringBuilder(bytes.length * 2);
    for (byte b : bytes) {
      b &= 0xff;
      if (b < 16) accum.append("0");
      accum.append(Integer.toHexString(b);
    }
    return accum.toString();
}
```

You're better off using an explicit `StringBuilder` of your own if this routine is going to be called a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [BigInteger](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28int,%20byte[]%29) for this.

Example:

```
(new BigInteger(1,bytes)).toString(16)
```

You will need to add an '0' at the beginning.

A more elegant solution (taken from [here](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3686)) is:

```
BigInteger i = new BigInteger(1,bytes);
System.out.println(String.format("%1$06X", i));
```

You need to know the number of bytes in advance in order to use the correct formatter.

Comment: That's indeed a nice oneliner (+1), but I've profiled it before, it's relatively slow and, above all, it doesn't prefix bytes < 0x10 with zeroes.

Comment: Only the first zero will not be prefixed. For example {8, 10, 12} will be converted to 80a0c. I have successfully used this for generation of MD5 hashes. I can't say anything about the performance.

Answer (score 1):

```
 private static String to2DigitsHex(byte[] bs) {
      String s = new BigInteger(bs).toString(16);
      return s.length()%2==0? s : "0"+s;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not taking any credit for this implementation as I saw it as part of a similar discussion and thought it was an elegant solution:

```
private static final String HEXES = "0123456789ABCDEF";

public String toHexString(byte[] bytes) {
    final StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(2 * bytes.length);
    for (final byte b : _bytes) {
        hex.append(HEXES.charAt((b & 0xF0) >> 4))
           .append(HEXES.charAt((b & 0x0F)));
    }
    return hex.toString();
}
```